# How to avoid duplicate code for refreshing token in this class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `Service` which makes various API calls using a `Client` class. The APIs require a `token` which can expire. This `token` is saved in the db so I only fetch for a new token when it expires. I’m looking for a clean way to write this code. Currently, the pseudo code looks something like this:

```
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    public void createUser() {
        Token token = readTokenFromDb();
        if (token.isExpired()) {
            token = client.readToken();
            save(token);
        }
        client.createUser(token);
    }

    public void readUsers() {
        Token token = readTokenFromDb();
        if (token.isExpired()) {
            token = client.readToken();
            save(token);
        }
        client.readUsers(token);
    }

    public void updateUsers() {
        // similar code
    }
    // many other similar methods
}
```

What's the best way to avoid the `if` block to refresh the token for every method? In other words, have one common place to do it.

If it matters, this is a Spring project, and the `Client` is using an `@Autowired` `RestTemplate` inside for calling the APIs.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
private Token checkToken(){
    Token token = readTokenFromDb();
    if (token.isExpired()) {
        token = client.readToken();
        save(token);
    }
    return token;
}
```

Methods:

```
public void readUsers() {
    Token token = checkToken();
    client.readUsers(token);
}
```

Comment: my method name is maybe not optimal :)

Comment: Is there even a better way? I was hoping to not have checkToken() before each client call.